# Conditionally display block of text with code inside string section

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to conditionally display this block of text but I don't understand how to put the part `nrow(subset(df, column == 1))` readable for the program and not inside the string.

```
`r if(nrow( subset(df,column == 1) != 0){"Multiple choice variable with nrow(subset(df, column == 1)) missing values."}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `paste` you could do:

Also note that there was a bug in your condition which I fixed.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: '2022-07-22'
---

```{r}
df <- data.frame(
  column = 1:2
)
```

`r if (nrow( subset(df,column == 1)) != 0) paste("Multiple choice variable with", nrow(subset(df, column == 1)), "missing values.") else ""`
````

[image]